# Events not displayed in full calendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4, fullcalendar-scheduler

I've been trying to display some events with fullcalendar but it's not working. 
I've been googling and trying different values but it never worked. 
For example I tried this :

```
                                events: [
                                {
                                    title  : 'event1',
                                    start  : '2020-04-01'
                                },
                                {
                                    title  : 'event2',
                                    start  : '2020-04-05',
                                    end    : '2020-04-07'
                                },
                                {
                                    title  : 'event3',
                                    start  : '2020-04-03T12:30:00',
                                    allDay : false // will make the time show
                                }
                            ],
```

and also this :

```
                                events: [
                                {"id":"1","start":"2020-04-14T13:00:00","end":"2020-04-14T1‌​6:00:00","title":"Pe‌​r Hour: 11.00,Per Mile: 11.00"},
                                {"id":"2","start":"2020-04-15T13:00:00","end":"2020-04-15T16‌​:00:00","title":"Per Hour: 11.00,Per Mile: 11.00"},
                                {"id":"3","start":"2020-04-16T13:00:00","end":"2020-04-16T16‌​:00:00","title":"Per Hour: 11.00,Per Mile: 11.00"}
                            ]
```

among other tests. All of the values that I tested were found on internet, from people sharing their experience, but for me none of them worked.

Any idea of what's wrong with these values ?

Then I'll write the script that will retrive the data from my db but first I have to make it work with hard-coded values.

---

I'll try to be clearer :
I copied / pasted this code from full calendar demo and it's working fine, displaying events correctly :

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    schedulerLicenseKey: 'GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source',
  plugins: [ 'resourceTimeGrid' ],
  timeZone: 'UTC',
  defaultView: 'resourceTimeGridFourDay',
  datesAboveResources: true,
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'resourceTimeGridDay,resourceTimeGridFourDay'
  },
  views: {
    resourceTimeGridFourDay: {
      type: 'resourceTimeGrid',
      duration: { days: 4 },
      buttonText: '4 days'
    }
  },
  resources: [
    { id: 'a', title: 'Room A' },
    { id: 'b', title: 'Room B' }
  ],
  events: 'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-events.json?with-resources=2'
});

calendar.render();  });
```

Then I commented the line that was retrieving the events from fullcalendar website and added my own hard-coded events, like this :

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    schedulerLicenseKey: 'GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source',
  plugins: [ 'resourceTimeGrid' ],
  timeZone: 'UTC',
  defaultView: 'resourceTimeGridFourDay',
  datesAboveResources: true,
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'resourceTimeGridDay,resourceTimeGridFourDay'
  },
  views: {
    resourceTimeGridFourDay: {
      type: 'resourceTimeGrid',
      duration: { days: 4 },
      buttonText: '4 days'
    }
  },
  resources: [
    { id: 'a', title: 'Room A' },
    { id: 'b', title: 'Room B' }
  ],
  //events: 'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-events.json?with-resources=2'
  events: [
                            {
                                title  : 'event1',
                                start  : '2020-04-01'
                            },
                            {
                                title  : 'event2',
                                start  : '2020-04-05',
                                end    : '2020-04-07'
                            },
                            {
                                title  : 'event3',
                                start  : '2020-04-03T12:30:00',
                                allDay : false // will make the time show
                            }
    ]
});

calendar.render();  });
```

And when I do so, the events are not displayed.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with either of these sets of events. Demo 1: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/jOPoqjq  Demo 2: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/OJVYNde . If you have a problem, it's being caused by something you haven't shown here. Have you checked for things like console errors? Is your calendar definitely focused on the correct month and year? Are you trying to use a resource-enabled view with events which don't have resource IDs? Could be a few reasons for there being an issue, but it's not something we can diagnose from the information you've provided so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the edit.

The reason is clearer now - you're using resource-enabled views, but your events don't have any matching resource IDs. So how is fullCalendar supposed to know which resource to place them on, do you think? It cannot decide, which means it can't display the events.

You can assign your events to different resources, depending on where they belong. Like this, for example:

```
events: [
  {
    title  : 'event1',
    start  : '2020-04-01',
    resourceId: 'b'
  },
  {
    title  : 'event2',
    start  : '2020-04-05',
    end    : '2020-04-07',
    resourceId: 'a'
  },
  {
    title  : 'event3',
    start  : '2020-04-03T12:30:00',
    allDay : false, // will make the time show
    resourceIds: ['a', 'b']
  }
]
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/LYVoZvK?editable=true&editors=001

Here is the relevant fullCalendar documentation page: [Associating Events with Resources](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resources-and-events)

Comment: One last comment though... I have issues when trying to pass php variable to the javascript... I inserted the value into an HTML input and then retrieved it inside Javascript variable like this : var planned_events = document.getElementById('planned_events').value; but the planned_events value contains strange caracters and it's not working...

Comment: I guess I have to find a way to get a json value and then convert it to javascript array, it should work.

Comment: You could do that, but a much better way would be to use a totally separate server-side script which returns the event data, then you can just define `events` as a URL, like in the fullcalendar demo. So if you have a PHP server you could write something like `events: "http:///www.example.com/events.php"`, where events.php would be a PHP script which accepts the "start" and "end" date parameters (which fullCalendar supplies to it automatically), and returns an array of events in JSON format. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed for more info.

Comment: If you're using a framework like Symfony (which I seem to remember from an earlier question that you are), then of course rather than an individual script, you'd be defining a route and a function in a controller which would return the JSON. Same concept, just a different implementation approach.

Comment: Actually I made it work with passing data to an input in json format, but your idea is much better. I'm still working on data saving and once I'm done I will change this part because my code isn't very nice. Thank you !

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/list-view is what I needed to learn about.